# Count the more then one specific match in string in Objects

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq, lambda

```
class SampleClass
{
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I have a list from Sample class elements -

```
var sampleClass = new SampleClass(Name = "HelloStackOverflow");
var sampleClass1 = new SampleClass(Name = "HelloStackOverflow");
var sampleClassWithDigit = new SampleClass(Name = "HelloStackOverflow1");

var listWithString = new List<SampleClass>();
listWithString.Add(sampleClass);
listWithString.Add(sampleClass1);
listWithString.Add(sampleClassWithDigit);
```

2 of the elements contains exactly the same phrase - "HelloStackOverflow"

the last one has the same phrase but its end with number - "HelloStackOverflow1"

I want to be able to count how many times the word HelloStackOverflow and the same word but with digit at the end is presented in the list

```
var countNumber = listWithString.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("HelloStackOverflow")).Count();
```

The Lambda above is getting only the first 2 elements that are match exactly with the pattern in the Coitans().
Is`t possible again with some Lambda or with some expression to match also the element/s that has the same name like the first 2 but also end with digit every time and getting the Count() of them - how many elements are HelloStackOverflow and HelloStackOverflow1 ?

Comment: Would you want to count `HelloStackOverflows`? `HelloStackOverflow12`? `HelloStackOverflow0`?

Comment: To me, it looks like you are receiving [3 items](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wFDChk)

Comment: `Contains` should work for that, if it would match exact strings it would be `==`

Comment: Could it be that your list of strings had a case difference in your original code?

Comment: Ran it myself and get 3 as the count

Comment: Tnx for answers.Mb the problems came from that in the List there is a object that has property Name.

Comment: I bowed you guys - there is List<People> for example and People class has property Name. Then i`m doing like this - var people = new People(); people.Name = HelloStackOverflows; List.Add(people); var peopleWithDigit = new People(); peopleWithDigit.Name = HelloStackOverflows1; List.Add(peopleWithDigit); Then the lambda above is returning 1 as Count()

Comment: Can you post your actual code?  It's the only way we can help

Comment: I posted my edited code...

Comment: `var sampleClass = new SampleClass(Name = "HelloStackOverflow");` doesn't compile. Can you include your actual code?

Comment: Basically im adding a value to the SampleClass`s property.

Comment: That code doesn't do that (it can't, it doesn't compile). Please update your post with your **actual** code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get 2 separate counters, one that counts how many instances contain `HelloStackOverflow` and then how many contain `HelloStackOverflow` followed by a number, you could use regex for the latter:

```
var listWithString = new List<string> {"HelloStackOverflow", "HelloStackOverflow", "HelloStackOverflow9"};
var justTextCount = listWithString.Count(x => x.Contains("HelloStackOverflow"));
var textWithNumberCount = listWithString.Count(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, @"HelloStackOverflow\d+"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> how many elements are HelloStackOverflow and HelloStackOverflow9

If I understand your question correctly then you can get the number of occurrences for each items using `GroupBy`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> occurences = listWithString
            .GroupBy(item => item)
            .ToDictionary(grouping => grouping.Key, grouping => grouping.Count());
```

You'll get a dictionary with the list item as the key and the number of occurences as the value so in your example it will be:

```
HelloStackOverflow -> 2
HelloStackOverflow9 -> 1
```